# Jquery DataTables serverside SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, server-side

I am JS newbie, trying to set datatables server side. Following their documentation [here](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html). I'm getting the following error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I have tried many lookups and recommendations from different forum, no success. Really appreciate if someone can help. Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#dataTables-example').dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "ajax.php",
        "fnServerData": function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            /* Add some data to send to the source, and send as 'POST' */
            aoData.push({
                "name": "min",
                "value": $('#min').val()
            });
            aoData.push({
                "name": "max",
                "value": $('#max').val()
            });
            $.ajax({
                "dataType": 'json',
                "type": "GET",
                "url": "ajax.php",
                "data": aoData,
                "success": fnCallback,
                "timeout": 15000, // optional if you want to handle timeouts (which you should)
                "error": handleAjaxError // this sets up jQuery to give me errors
            });
        }
    });
    $('#min').change(function() {
        oTable.fnFilter($(this).val(), 0);
    });
    $('#max').change(function() {
        oTable.fnFilter($(this).val(), 0);
    });
});

function handleAjaxError(xhr, textStatus, error) {
    if (textStatus === 'timeout') {
        alert('The server took too long to send the data.');
    } else {
        alert(error);
    }
}
```

In my server side code for now I have not overridden the `$Query` and `$Where`, so custom filter on server side but I guess that should not throw error.

```
<?php
    $table = 'tbl_test';

    $columns = array(
        'DS',
        'PUR',
        'RegDate',
        'ACTDATE',
        'BUSINESS NAME', 
        'CITY'      
    );

    $sql_details = array(
        'user' => 'root',
        'pass' => '',
        'db'   => 'samarty',
        'host' => 'localhost'
    );

    require( 'ssp.class.php' );

    echo json_encode(
        SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
    );
?>
```

Edit 1: Console.log

```
 jquery.dataTables.min.js:39 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property    'length' of undefinedvb @ jquery.dataTables.min.js:39

 (anonymous function) @ jquery.dataTables.min.js:37i @ jquery.dataTables.min.js:35j @ jquery.js:3094k.fireWith @ jquery.js:3206x @ jquery.js:8259(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:8600
```

Comment: The error means your `ajax.php` file is returning HTML not JSON, most likely due to a 404 or 500 error. Check the request in the console to see the exact response.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan, It's shown me all the errors :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Can you help me with the error. I have updated my question with console log. Also plz put your above comment as answer so that I can accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datatable serverside script need the `$primary_key`. I could not see that in your code.